# Creating Second User on Creating First User in Meteor.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

How can we automatically create a second user when the user registers (the first user) from a form generated using the `useraccounts:core` package?

Running a `Accounts.createUser` from within `Accounts.onCreateUSer` causes an error `Exception while invoking method 'ATCreateUserServer' TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {

    // Create Primary User
    if(!user.type) {

        // Set user.type as 'user'
        user.type = 'user'

        // Create Secondary User
        Accounts.createUser({
            username: options.profile.slaveName,
            password: options.profile.slaveName,
            type: 'slave',
            profile: {
                firstName: user.profile.firstName,
                lastName: user.profile.lastName
            }
        })

        user.profile = options.profile
        return user
    }


    // Create Secondary User
    if(user.type == 'slave') {
        user.profile = options.profile
        return user
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you're conflating the `user` argument and the `options` argument. For instance, the `type` field comes in through the `options` argument, not `user`.

The following code worked for me:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  // Create Primary User
  if(!options.type) {
    // Set user.type as 'user'
    options.type = 'user'

    // Create Secondary User
    Accounts.createUser({
        username: options.profile.slaveName,
        password: options.profile.slaveName,
        type: 'slave',
        profile: {
            firstName: options.profile.firstName,
            lastName: options.profile.lastName
        }
    });

    user.profile = options.profile
    return user
  }


  // Create Secondary User
  if(options.type == 'slave') {
    user.profile = options.profile
    return user
  }
});
```

I then tested like so:

```
// console
Accounts.createUser({username: "guest", password: "guest", profile: {slaveName: 'guestslave', firstName: "Greatest", lastName: "Ever"}})
Meteor.users.find({username: {$regex: 'guest'}}).fetch()
> [returned two user objects]
```